# Why I am getting this error while executing a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling to understand error in below code -

```
d for d, d1 in zip([0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05])
```

With this I am getting below error -

```
  d for d, d1 in zip([0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05])
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you please help me to understand this error and how to resolve this?

Comment: As the error says, the code doesn't mean anything. What did you intend the code to mean?

Comment: As part of a list comprehension this code would be valid, but we need feedback from the OP,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python doesn't understand what to do with multiple values that will return after `d for d, d1 in zip([0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05])`

you need to enclose that within a list like `[d for d, d1 in zip([0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05])]` for it to work. this way python will return a list as a result.

Answer (score -1):

The zip() function returns a zip object, which is an iterator of tuples where the first item in each passed iterator is paired together, and then the second item in each passed iterator are paired together etc.